# Converting HDF to TIFF using batch processing with gdal_translate

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, batch, hdf

I have a huge MODIS dataset and I need to translate them to tiff from hdf.

My input path is: `C:\Users\HP\Desktop\deneme\ham_veri`
and hopefully, the output path is: `C:\Users\HP\Desktop\deneme\yeni`

This is what I'm trying to run for batch processing:

```
FORFILES /m MOD10A2.A2016321.h20v05.006.2016340133152.hdf C:\Users\HP\Desktop\deneme\ham_veri "cmd /c gdal_translate -sds -of HDF4_SDS:hdf:@file:01 C:\Users\HP\Desktop\deneme\yeni\MOD10A2.A2016321.h20v05.006.2016340133152.tif"
```

and this is what I got from command prompt:

```
ERROR 6: Too many command options '%C:\Users\HP\Desktop\deneme\yeni%\@MOD10A2.A2016321.h20v05.006.2016340133152.tiff'
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have one file, why do you use `FORFILES`? Just wondering.

Comment: I have many .hdf files in sub-folders. But currently what I'm trying to do is to extract all the hdf files in one folder manually (because I don't know how to make it with python and don't want to make everything too complicated for a newbie) and then write a code to translate hdf files to tiff with batch processing. Isn't that the code I should use?

Comment: I'm not an expert on gdal_translate. I guess you should use `/s` for `forfiles` command to get files in subfolders. This is not related to the error, tough.

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea. I'm going to work on it. Btw I think we are in the same country. Aren't we allowed to speak our native language here?

Comment: If you have QGIS you can run the gdal translate command in batch.  The Run as a Batch Process button shows in the form that opens when you open the tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, make sure `forfile` command returns the files you want to process.

The next command prints all HDF files' name in the folder:

```
forfiles /p C:\Users\HP\Desktop\deneme\ham_veri /m *.hdf /c "cmd /c echo @path
```

You may think of using this:

```
FORFILES /m *.hdf /P C:\Users\HP\Desktop\deneme\ham_veri /C "cmd /C gdal_translate -sds @file C:\Users\HP\Desktop\deneme\yeni\@fname.tif"
```

But unfortunately, `@fname` returns file name with double quotes like `"file"`. So, the full output path would be like `C:\Users\HP\Desktop\deneme\yeni\"file".tif` and this path is incorrect because of double quotes.

Therefore, you need to get rid of them. I, finally, found a solution as follows:

```
FORFILES /m *.hdf /P C:\Users\HP\Desktop\deneme\ham_veri /C "cmd /Q /C for %I in (@fname) do gdal_translate -sds -of GTiff @file C:\Users\HP\Desktop\deneme\yeni\%~I.tif"
```

Comment: No error messages, it worked. Thank you for the brief information.